# Why did they put the Doctor in a fez?

Tags: doctor-who

It's true, Fezes are cool.

But has anyone ever given an explanation why Fezes?

[image: Matt Smith's Doctor wearing his tweed suit, bow tie and fez with the caption: It's a fez. I wear a fez now. Fezzes are cool!]

What made Moffat, Matt or whoever else chose Fezzes pick them out of all the other hats?

Comment: Yeah, they should have given him a [deerstalker](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U5q2c.jpg). Deerstalkers are cool.

Comment: @MrLister so are [Stetsons](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5ma6uJYjn1r8y5loo1_500.gif)

Comment: I think the explanation *is*, "Fezes are cool!".

Comment: @BrendanLong by whose account?

Comment: Why not Zoidberg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steven Moffat came up with the idea, as indicated in an episode of *Doctor Who Confidential*. Beyond that, there was no big reveal on the reason behind it from what I could tell. Most sources appeared to point to *Doctor Who Confidential* for any and all behind-the-scenes information on the origin of the fez.

https://doctorwho.tumblr.com/post/9026641400/ilove-mattsmith-blog-steven-mentioned-the-fez